# How to underline TextView next to Spinner (continue Spinner background for TextView)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spinner, styling

I'm trying to create this UI:

[image: hard to build UI]

That is to say, there is a TextView on the left side and a Spinner on the right. And both are underlined with a single line. A Spinner default style already has underline (with the style and background image). So the task is to continue somehow it's background to a TextView.

Neeed your help, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//example main

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

//example R.layout.custom_spinner_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

//example R.layout.main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--stuff-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/anotherField1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:spinnerStyle"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Left" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--stuff-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/anotherField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Results:

[image: pic1][image: pic2]

Comment: Thank you for the descritpive answer! Pictures are better than words.

Comment: 2 addon questions: 1. What is the idea behind using RelativeLayout/android:addStatesFromChildren="true" (I'd checked - works without it)? 2. Is it possible to define a width of the dropdown list like on the screen [narow dropdown list](http://i59.tinypic.com/28hmvch.jpg)?

Comment: 1. there would be no highlight onClick (imho on my device) 2. soory, I have no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a style for the spinner, the style you used in the picture is:

style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own SpinnerAdapter for the Spinner (you should `extend BaseAdapter` for this). Implement `getView()` to define the view that the spinner shows as the selected item. Implement `getDropDownView()` to define the views that the spinner dropdown shows. You can easily make `getView()` return something like a `LinearLayout` to have text on the left and the right.

Comment: This way I thought to go with. But I wanted a simpler (elegnt) solution and @deadfish made it!

Answer (score 0):

Below link work for me.

https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-border-between-items.html

res/drawable/spinner_item_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff2632"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#d7ffa2"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_border"
    />
```